# OneDrive video from url has no audio. How to change the code to hear the movie?

Tags: html, audio, html5-video, onedrive, codec

When I open the video on OneDrive with a browser, it has no audio at all. I think there are some codec problems, but can I change anything to get the audio from the movie?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <video controls style="width: 100%; height: 100%; preload="auto" playsinline="" autoplay="" src="https://uszeged-my.sharepoint.com/personal/toth_akos_o365_u-szeged_hu/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=%2Fpersonal%2Ftoth_akos_o365_u-szeged_hu%2FDocuments%2FFilmek%2FThe+Witcher+S02%2FThe.Witcher.S02E01.720p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.Atmos.H.264.HUN.ENG-PTHD.mkv" type="video/mkv"></video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **(1)** There is nothing in your shown code that could affect the sound. **(2)** Not sure what browser you use but MKV is based on WebM (same structure) so maybe your browser can luckily understand the picture part from the MKV bytes (it thinks its WebM file). **(3)** Use [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) to find out the a/v codecs inside your MKV container.  Video should be H264/AVC and audio should be AAC or MP3 for the browser. **(4)** For `<video>` use MP4 for the widest support of browser brands. Will MKV work in Safari or Firefox on iPhone? MP4 would work...

Comment: PS: You'll have to find a tool (_eg:_ FFmpeg or HandBrake) to do the file conversion from MKV to MP4. If the video part is H264 then it can be cut/pasted (fast) into MP4 (is called muxing) but I think your audio part will have to be converted from whatever it is now into the AAC format (slow & depends on file length).

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestion. I thought I have an opportunity to give an audio codec as a parameter, and browsers would have recognized it. I'll convert those videos to the right format.